# Modify a line in a scope with Ansible

Tags: scope, ansible

I need to modify a line in a file.  Only problem, the line appears multiple times, but in different scopes.  Like in this example from wso2 configuration manual :

```
<KeyStore>
    <Location>${carbon.home}/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
    <Type>JKS</Type>
    <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
    <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
    <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
</KeyStore>

<TrustStore>
    <!-- trust-store file location -->
    <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
    <!-- trust-store type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.) -->
    <Type>JKS</Type> 
    <!-- trust-store password -->
    <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
</TrustStore>
```

I would need for example to modify the `<Password>` entry with one value in the `<Keystore>` scope, and with a second different value in the `<TrustStore>` scope in order to have  different passwords.  Can the lineinfile module do that ?  Or is there any other way ?

PS.
Using a template is not the solution I am looking for, as I would like to use this to modify preexisting servers and not lose any local modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html), because it handles every line of the file separately – so there's no context from other lines possible.
Regex in `lineinfile` is not multiline.

You can use [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html) – it uses multiline regex.
For example:

```
- replace:
    backup: yes
    dest: config.xml
    regexp: '(<{{ item.scope }}>[\S\s]*<Password>)(?!{{ item.password }}<).*(</Password>[\S\s]*</{{ item.scope }}>)'
    replace: '\1{{ item.password }}\2'
  with_items:
    - scope: KeyStore
      password: foo
    - scope: TrustStore
      password: bar
```

Keep in mind that this solution is not bulletproof – scope names and password shouldn't have any XML special characters or regular expression sequences. Also I can't say for sure how it handles nested XML blocks with the same scope name.
But for general cases it should be fine.
There's even a try to be idempotent – it will not match a block if the password is the same.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly.  The module works and your proposed solution is perfect, although I am not sure about the negative look ahead grouping (the `<` at the end is confusing me).  Here the line I tried that also works and that I can understand ```- name: Test of remplace module
      replace: dest=/tmp/carbon.xml regexp='(\s*<KeyStore>)((?:\n.*)*)(<Password>)(.*)(</Password>)((?:\n.*)*)(</KeyStore>)' replace='\1\2\3ThePassWord\5\6\7' backup=yes ```.  I would upvote your answer, but I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Negative lookahead with `password<` meant to skip blocks with password already set (without it your task will always return changed state), and `<` is added to avoid situation when password was `foobar` and you want to set it to `foo` – in this case lookahead without `<` will match part of `foobar` and password won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible `lineinfile` `regex` parameter can match multiple lines. There is no problem in that beside that the regex would be long and hard to understand and maintain.

As you are trying to manipulate `XML` [ansible-xml](https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml) module might be a good option to solve this problem.