# Rows in a group remove

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm using the replace module of Ansible (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html).

My file is:

```
...
net route-domain /Common/0 {
    id 0
    vlans {
        /thisrow/AAAA_yyyyy
        /Common/http-tunnel
        /Common/socks-tunnel
        /Common/BIGIP-HA
        /thisrow/AAAA_xxxxx
    }
}
...
```

I need to remove all rows containing /thisrow/ inside vlans.

I'm using this regex: `(^    vlans )(?P<vlanrow>){([^}]*)}{0}.*vasgk.*\n` but I don't know how to remove ALL *thisrow* from *vlanrow* group

Thanks,
Riccardo

This is not a dupl. Ansible is not the problem. The problem is the regular expression matching just 1 time thisrow. Try it on https://regex101.com/r/n3rRsl/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify a line in a scope with Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858486/modify-a-line-in-a-scope-with-ansible)

Comment: @Konstantin: could you help me. This il not a dupl

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't pay attention that you want multiple matches inside single context. I guess you're out of luck here, because `replace` module use `re.subn` function, which doesn't support overlapping matches.

Comment: So, with regex is impossible to solve?

Comment: I'm afraid, not possible. Still you can use a nasty hack to make `retry` `until` task and apply replace to delete row one by one until status of the task is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with the following playbook, using a little modified regexp of yours and the sample data from regex101 you provided.

#### playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - replace:
        dest: /home/user/config.conf
        regexp: '(^    vlans )(?P<vlanrow>){([^}]*)}{0}(\s{8}/vasgk.*)\n'
        replace: '\1\2{\3'
      register: result
      until: result.changed == False
      retries: 4094 # you can't have more vlans!
```

This is the result:

```
net route-domain /Common/0 {
    id 0
    vlans {
        /Common/http-tunnel
        /Common/socks-tunnel
        /Common/BIGIP-HA
    }
}
```

It seems to be quite slow though, but should give you an idea. Hope that helps!

**Edit:**
changed
`(^    vlans )(?P<vlanrow>){([^}]*)}{0}(.*/vasgk.*)\n`
to `(^    vlans )(?P<vlanrow>){([^}]*)}{0}(\s{8}/vasgk.*)\n`, this fixed problems with spacing.

Comment: Cool. Just changed this for better performances --> until: '"replacements made" not in result.msg'