# Edit json file using ansible

Tags: ansible, file-manipulation

I am trying to edit a particular JSON file using Ansible. The file is present in remote servers which have to be logged in using LDAP authentication.

The file path is `/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json`

and the line that I want to edit is as follows:

```
"subscriptions": ["Nginx", "Primus", "B2B", "Docker_Process_Check", "EBS", "base"],
```

I want to add one more value (`"filebeat"`) in that line which after that should look like

```
"subscriptions": ["Nginx", "Primus", "B2B", "Docker_Process_Check", "EBS", "base","filebeat"],
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your operating system?

Comment: It is mac os..But I am trying to update the same in multiple ec2 linux instances..I was trying with lineinfile inbuilt module but that does not work for json I guess..Any inbuilt module present for doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's still no builtin module for JSON manipulation.

Either use 3rd-party module (like [ghetto-json](https://github.com/FauxFaux/ansible-ghetto-json)),

or make a complex regular expression with [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/replace_module.html) module (i.e. search for `"subscriptions": [<...>]` and place `,"filebeat"` just before closing `]`. You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to craft and test required expression.

Please also inspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861548/2795592) answer for additional info.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to create .JSON file using Ansible ?  My Requirement is to get the inputs from the user (through survey/prompt) and use these inputs as the values (in "key" : "value" pairs) of .JSON file